# Visual Studio 2012 Project unavailable - project is Unloaded

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, projects-and-solutions

I am trying to open a code which was built by a different guy. I am not sure which version of VS it was built in or any other details.
When I try to open the solution I always get Project unavailable error.
As per many answers in this forum I tried removing and adding the projects with no luck.

Below are the details. Let me know if you need anything else, thanks a lot for the help!

[Screenshot of the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiPT5.jpg)

> Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
>
> ## Visual Studio 2012 Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "FileDeploymentService", "FileDeploymentService\FileDeploymentService.csproj",
>
> "{23FDA660-259A-486C-89E5-8CB5197A8759}" EndProject
>   Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "DlaDataAccess",
>   "..\DLA.Net_BackEnd_App\DlaDataAccess\DlaDataAccess.csproj",
>   "{85CE74BA-B16C-4977-9EE9-F3149DEBBED1}" EndProject
>   Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "PBI.FDS.Factory",
>   "PBI.FDS.Factory\PBI.FDS.Factory.csproj",
>   "{C8D59D03-6B2C-4DA2-BAC0-5AB9A36888D9}" EndProject
>   Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "PBI.FDS.Model",
>   "PBI.FDS.Model\PBI.FDS.Model.csproj",
>   "{95317690-DAE0-4898-A19E-66DFA75997D4}" EndProject
>   Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") =
>   "PBI.FDS.Processor", "PBI.FDS.Processor\PBI.FDS.Processor.csproj",
>   "{2AC75BE6-3B59-4A1A-801E-4E807DCEFAA3}" EndProject
>   Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "PBI.FDS.Dal",
>   "PBI.FDS.Dal\PBI.FDS.Dal.csproj",
>   "{7A77AA42-058B-4B34-9664-114781AC477E}" EndProject Global
>     GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
>         Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU       Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
>     EndGlobalSection    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) =
>   postSolution      {23FDA660-259A-486C-89E5-8CB5197A8759}.Debug|Any
>   CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
>         {23FDA660-259A-486C-89E5-8CB5197A8759}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 =
>   Debug|Any CPU         {23FDA660-259A-486C-89E5-8CB5197A8759}.Release|Any
>   CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
>         {23FDA660-259A-486C-89E5-8CB5197A8759}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 =
>   Release|Any CPU       {85CE74BA-B16C-4977-9EE9-F3149DEBBED1}.Debug|Any
>   CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
>         {85CE74BA-B16C-4977-9EE9-F3149DEBBED1}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 =
>   Debug|Any CPU         {85CE74BA-B16C-4977-9EE9-F3149DEBBED1}.Release|Any
>   CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
>         {85CE74BA-B16C-4977-9EE9-F3149DEBBED1}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 =
>   Release|Any CPU       {C8D59D03-6B2C-4DA2-BAC0-5AB9A36888D9}.Debug|Any
>   CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
>         {C8D59D03-6B2C-4DA2-BAC0-5AB9A36888D9}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 =
>   Debug|Any CPU         {C8D59D03-6B2C-4DA2-BAC0-5AB9A36888D9}.Release|Any
>   CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
>         {C8D59D03-6B2C-4DA2-BAC0-5AB9A36888D9}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 =
>   Release|Any CPU       {95317690-DAE0-4898-A19E-66DFA75997D4}.Debug|Any
>   CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
>         {95317690-DAE0-4898-A19E-66DFA75997D4}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 =
>   Debug|Any CPU         {95317690-DAE0-4898-A19E-66DFA75997D4}.Release|Any
>   CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
>         {95317690-DAE0-4898-A19E-66DFA75997D4}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 =
>   Release|Any CPU       {2AC75BE6-3B59-4A1A-801E-4E807DCEFAA3}.Debug|Any
>   CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
>         {2AC75BE6-3B59-4A1A-801E-4E807DCEFAA3}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 =
>   Debug|Any CPU         {2AC75BE6-3B59-4A1A-801E-4E807DCEFAA3}.Release|Any
>   CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
>         {2AC75BE6-3B59-4A1A-801E-4E807DCEFAA3}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 =
>   Release|Any CPU       {7A77AA42-058B-4B34-9664-114781AC477E}.Debug|Any
>   CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
>         {7A77AA42-058B-4B34-9664-114781AC477E}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 =
>   Debug|Any CPU         {7A77AA42-058B-4B34-9664-114781AC477E}.Release|Any
>   CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
>         {7A77AA42-058B-4B34-9664-114781AC477E}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 =
>   Release|Any CPU   EndGlobalSection    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) =
>   preSolution       HideSolutionNode = FALSE    EndGlobalSection
>     GlobalSection(Performance) = preSolution        HasPerformanceSessions =
>   true  EndGlobalSection EndGlobal

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the output window. It usually contains the error message.

Comment: Thanks Drutten, the output window is just empty. No error messages. Could it be a version compatible issue? is yes, how can I identify what is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the issue doesn't seems to be a Visual Studio related issue. If the issue is Visual Studio related then when you tried to open the Solution it will show a Incompatibility issue.

To resolve the issue first try to run Visual Studio in `Administrator` mode and open the solution. Sometimes Visual Studio cannot open projects without `Administrator` privileges.

Comment: I get the error of incompatibility when I try in VS10. But this error pops when I try to open in VS12.

Comment: @TheDumbCoder Try to open the solution in Administrator mode